# Improving HTTP POST speed?

Tags: c#, .net, http, post

Sending a HTTP POST to an asp.net web form which inserts into multiple tables in a database with data I passed in the POST along with POST to another external API. The load time takes anywhere between 5 - 60 seconds.

This isn't good enough. I just POST simply like so to a URL:

```
var postData = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "authorization", db.EXAMPLE.Where(x => x.id == 0).FirstOrDefault().Key},
    { "korefor", korefora },
    {"koreforname", clientname },
    {"koreforkeywords", clientkeywords },
    { "korename", korename }, 
    { "set_instant", i },
    { "set_engine", engine },
    { "set_language", language },
    { "set_location", location },
    { "set_rankfor", decidedevice }, 
    { "set_mainurl", mainurl },
    { "set_compurls", compurls },
    { "set_email", emails },
     "set_autokore", autokoreno }
};
using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(amend(postData));
    byte[] byteResult = wc.UploadData("http://hagfhhgf.co.uk/Default.aspx", "POST", byteArray);
    string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteResult);
}
```

This can be a lot of data.

What I am asking overall: **How can I speed this up?**

Maybe one of the following?

- POST to something that just saves all data in database temp table and then have another tool which looks at that table and handles correctly.
- Not wait for response

Comment: have you identified exactly what the most time-consuming functions are? is the post what is slow, or the operations on the server side?

Comment: Yes, mostly because of inserting to database and POST to other external APIs. For example, a part of this inserts keywords to a database table and then POST each one off to another API to receive information for. However this is a simple response and the main response for it is sent to another tool to be parsed. Some POST will contain 1000+ keywords. This is slow.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your server setup, we've had the same issues a long time ago, the solution for us was to create a windows service and set up an MSMQ, we dumped all postdata to the MSMQ and let the service pick up the data and do the processing, that way we offloaded that entire thing from the ASP.NET site. Today you can probably achieve the same with ASP.NET Queueing and WCF though.

Comment: A Word of caution though, our solution was for an internal Project. Doing it on a public site might incurr some pretty hefty wait times while the processing takes Place if you have many visitors.

Comment: Okay, thank you. This is on our dev site which is only internal use and it will be used as a tool by employees within the business to generate an in-depth ranking analysis report.

Comment: How are results used? For example, user makes a request which lasts 5-60 seconds. What can he do until it is completed? And what can he do after it? Does he get table or something else?